# Retrieving specific sub-section of results

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Can a query be filtered so that just rows 20 - 30 are returned ?

This does not seem to be mentioned here : 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using an integer offset skips a specified number of results before returning the first one. Substituting the following line in the example above would return the sixth through tenth tallest people instead of the five tallest:

```
return pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withOffset(5).limit(5));
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Retrieving_Results

Please notice that the entities are still retrieved internally, if you want to reduce the datastore operations, consider using a [query cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors) instead. ([JDO documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Query_Cursors))

Comment: this will reduce the number of 'Datastore Read Operations' ?

Comment: Nope, the entities are still retrieved internally. You may want consider using a [query cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors) instead. (I updated the answer)

Comment: adding a new FilterPredicate to reduce the number of rows returned will reduce the number of 'Datastore Read Operations' ?

Comment: Yes, if you use a filter, datastore will only retrieve the entities which matches the filter, which will reduce the read operations.

Comment: @user470184 You should also take a look at the [Memcache Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview) - it's perfectly suited to cache things like common queries. And Memcache calls are free.